# Sorting xml nodes by attributes using xml.dom.minidom

Tags: python, xml, sorting

I want to sort some nodes of my xml by a specific attribute using xml.dom.minidom? Any help is appreciated.
From this:

```
    <Node Name="A" Position = "4"/>
    <Node Name="B" Position = "1"/>
    <Node Name="D" Position = "3"/>
    <Node Name="C" Position = "2"/>
```

to this:

```
    <Node Name="B" Position = "1"/>
    <Node Name="C" Position = "2"/>
    <Node Name="D" Position = "3"/>
    <Node Name="A" Position = "4"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: 1. You parse the XML from the file.
2. You sort the items.
3. You write the XML to a file.

I think you need to be a bit more specific to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get the nodes and sort them:

```
nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName('Node')
nodes.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.attributes['Position'].value))
```

Then write your nodes back to the file.